# removeAttr / addClass issue on IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, internet-explorer-6

This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245519/class-not-being-applied-in-ie6-using-addclass) but the issue wasn't resolved.

Please see this jsfiddle on IE6 : http://jsfiddle.net/RnsxM/2/

Basically a sprite image (not png fixed) won't update correctly in IE6. The class seems to be applied (and works without javascript) but the combinaison removeAttr + addClass seems broken.

I tried :

- `!important` css statement
- use of `background-position-x` or `background-position-y`

Does someone know a workaround ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not to do with scripting, this is a simple CSS brokenness. Something in IE6's selector engine can't cope with the idea of there being two `#id.class` rules with the same `#id` on a single stylesheet. This shorter example demonstrates:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #sprite.pos1 { background: red; }
    #sprite.pos2 { background: yellow; }
</style>
<div id="sprite" class="pos2">Hello</div> <!-- White in IE6! -->
```

You can avoid it by putting the IDs and classes on different elements, or just breaking the stylesheet up into two:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #sprite.pos1 { background: red; }
</style>
<style type="text/css">
    #sprite.pos2 { background: yellow; }
</style>
<div id="sprite" class="pos2">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Great thanks i resolved it by using the parent element id `#parent .posX`

Answer (score 0):

@bobince is right. I'm make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RnsxM/12/) and run it in [IEtester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) and I see that IE6 does not accept the selector:

```
#sprite.pos1
```

but accepts:

```
.pos1
```

I think basically is that and I recommend you that make an alternative selector for IE6, something like this:

```
#sprite.pos1 { background-position: -120px 0; }
.pos1 { _background-position: -120px 0; }
#sprite.pos2 { background-position: -240px 0; }
.pos2 { _background-position: -240px 0; }
```